# AngularJS translate dynamic string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) module for translation, but i have dynamic string which doesn't get translated.

I have tried this ways:

```
{{ data.foo | translate }}
```

This didn't work.

And i tried using his own directive:

```
 <span translate>{{ data.foo }}</span>
```

Using this method i get in output result of data.foo without translation.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not have the translationProvider configured correctly.  You should have something like this in your config:

```
$translateProvider.translations({
    'TRANSLATEME': 'Here is the translation'
});
```

and data.foo needs to equal `TRANSLATEME`.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Mjatot0Ufq9EFB9MUOn?p=preview) showing it working.

Comment: I just found out that something like `<span translate>FOO.BAR.{{ data.foo }}</span>` doesn't work. It has to be `<span translate>{{ 'FOO.BAR.' + data.foo }}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a string matching a translation key in data.foo ? is so :

```
<span translate="{{data.foo}}"></span>
```

definitely works; as well as :

```
<span>{{ data.foo | translate}}</span>
```

Comment: Ha! For some reason I read your comment as "I get undefined jack"... which was highly amusing for me. @Jack